# Rails how to pass ID in views - NameError in MessagesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to remember again pure Rails with view in html.erb. In my controller I've got an action which allows me to replay to original message from my inbox:

```
def create
  orignal_message = current_user.inbox.messages.find_by(id: params[:original_message_id])

  inbox = if orignal_message.created_at > 3.days.ago 
             orignal_message.moderator.inbox
          else
             original_message.admin.inbox
          end

  @message = Message.create(
    inbox: inbox
    body: params[:message][:body]
  )
end
```

As you see if the original message will be older than 3 days the reply should goes to the moderator.outbox, if it's fresh new - go to the admin outbox. How to handle that sort of action in view to fetch this original message and reply on?

In my `show.html.erb` I've got simple:
`<%= link_to "Answer", new_message_path, class: "btn-primary" %>`

Which gives me an error:

```
NameError in MessagesController#create
undefined local variable or method `original_message' for #<MessagesController:0x00007fcf969bb618>
```

Comment: `original_message` != `orignal_message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in your controller. Sometimes you use `original_message` and sometimes `orignal_message`. Fix those and it should be fine